# No Sound and volume is not muted

Tags: sound

Using an HP Pavilion 14, that came with Windows 10 Home, and cannot hear any sounds. All settings checked where volume is not muted and no sound can be produced by applications or web browsers.

Tried testing speakers before and after installing Alasmixer from Synaptic Package Manager with no change. The only sound I'm able to receive is when using "trying distro's"; not able to hear sounds when OS's are installed alongside Windows. No sound has been able to be produced with.

Have tried other Ubuntu flavors, and other Distros after install and none produce sound on this machine.

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 131
    Memory at b1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening up "Software & Updates" and checking the "Additional Drivers" tab to see if you have any proprietary drivers available for your sound card?  You can get there by searching for "Drivers" in most dashes/application menus/etc.

Comment: Had sound today for some time, just worked with no extra maintenance in Terminal; then just went dead and I haven't went back to check. Whenever I run Updates it's checking for drivers also and there are none available.